# How to download torrents from the office?

Tags: bittorrent, http

I have torrents blocked in my office. Was wondering whether there are any sites which allow to download torrents to their server so that we can download them via HTTP.

If I have my home system running, can I get the files downloaded from my office?

Comment: I do not know of anything like this, but I do not recommend pushing your limits of your office network rules.

Comment: You might want to add a related question "Why did I get fired from my job for downloading torrents?"

Comment: Please to be not circumventing the security controls your company has put into place, for your sake.

Comment: Shouldn't you be... you know... working?

Comment: Can't you just start your torrents at home when you leave for work and come back to them when your off work?

Comment: @Nifle - you're downvoting him for editing his own question ?!

Comment: "Why did I get fired from my job for downloading torrents?"
<-- EPICSOME!!!

Comment: enjoying ur comments!

Comment: +1 to Bruce's comment - love it.  You should take the friendly advice.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would install [µTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) on my home computer and set up the [WebUI](http://www.utorrent.com/documentation/webui/).

Comment: Yes, a Web UI would be good. Another good Web UI option is Transmission, if your home box is Mac or Linux.

Comment: Yeah, when on Mac or Linux Transmission is a very good option. Used it myself a couple of times :)

Answer (score 13):

If you have Dropbox, you could use it to [remotely start BitTorrent downloads](http://blog.gesteves.com/post/84438959/start-bittorrent-downloads-remotely-with-dropbox). Basically what you do is set up your BitTorrent client at home to automatically start downloads when .torrent files are added to a folder inside your Dropbox, and then you add .torrent files to that folder from your office via the [Dropbox web UI](https://www.getdropbox.com/home/) and they'll automatically start on the other side.

Answer (score 8):

If your office has blocked torrent activity, there has to be a good reason.
It is usually not just about bandwidth utilization.

Meanwhile, if you have a home machine active while you are at work, you can control it to work torrents.
This leaves the office network disconnect with the torrent traffic itself.
It becomes entirely your responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the bit torrent protocol is just to be able to distribute the bandwidth across all the peers. What you're suggesting defeats that purpose.

The best you can do is indeed like @nik suggests try to control your home machine (using something like [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com)) and download the torrents there.

Answer (score 2):

What you described is called a **torrent relay**.
You can run a relay on your own server or use one of the public relay services.

An example of a public torrent relay is [**www.torrentrelay.com**](http://www1.torrentrelay.com/). Their claim is:

> Download your torrents to any device
>   that supports viewing web pages (just
>   like this one does).

The basic service is free, but it is restricted to 500 KBps. If you want more you will have to pay them.

According to [this article](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/10/29/download-bt-bittorrent-files-via-http-with-imageshack-torrent-drive/) there is also a way to (ab)use ImageShack as torrent relay.

Comment: Can I setup this torrent relay service in my site? How to do that?

Comment: To run your own relay you need a machine with unrestricted access to the internet. This won't work from your office.

Comment: I have a website. Can I setup a Torrent relay service there, so that I can download with HTTP from office

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten around some restrictions with [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).  But, don't blame me if you get fired for leaching your company bandwidth. :)

Comment: Do you happen to know how this bypasses the restrictions as set up by the system administrator? The http://www.freedownloadmanager.org website does not seem to host some user manual. (And I guess it's not only the bandwidth that is a reason to block this, or to get fired.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a virtual private server, than you can install a command line torrent client on that like rtorrent and download the completed torrents via http in office, but if its shared hosting, it can get your hosting account blocked. If you dont want to use cli client, install torrentflux on your webserver, it has a nice webgui

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a seedbox.

Comment: rent a seedbox and be done with it. +1

Comment: I would upvote this answer if I knew what a seedbox was.  Can you update your answer with more information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing the following information as knowledge and do not intend it to be used for any illegal or malicious activities :).
I'm assuming you are on a windows machine. In that case you can download a free software called bitvise tunnelier. If you have an external SSH account, you could use the software to ssh to it and use port forwarding and setup a socks server on your computer. You could then set the proxy settings on your torrent client to use socks proxy and set the host as 127.0.0.1 and the port as the one that tunnelier is listening on. This will get torrents to work (also you can set the same proxy settings in your browser to access blocked websites).
If on linux, run this:

```
ssh -D PORT user@external-ssh-server
```

and in your torrent client/browser set the host as 127.0.0.1 and the port as PORT.
Hope this helps.