# Which torrent apps work headless (from command line only)?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bittorrent, headless

There's a question on here about [what torrent apps work well remotely](https://superuser.com/questions/17904/how-to-download-torrents-from-the-office), but I'm hoping to find out one that works well through a command line interface, preferably with no GUI.

What torrent apps would you recommend for running from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at [**deluge**](http://deluge-torrent.org/). It is cross-platform, and is excellent as a headless app.

> **Deluge is a full-featured  BitTorrent
>   client for Linux, OS X, Unix and
>   Windows.** It uses  libtorrent in it's
>   backend and features multiple
>   user-interfaces including: GTK+, web
>   and console. It has been designed
>   using the client server model with a
>   daemon process that handles all the
>   bittorrent activity. ***The Deluge daemon
>   is able to run on headless machines
>   with the user-interfaces being able to
>   connect remotely from any platform.***
>
> Deluge features a rich plugin
>   collection; in fact, most of Deluge's
>   functionality is available in the form
>   of plugins.
>
> Deluge was created with the intention
>   of being lightweight and unobtrusive.
>   It is our belief that downloading
>   shouldn't be the primary task on your
>   computer and therefore shouldn't
>   monopolize system resources.
>
> Deluge is not designed for any one
>   desktop environment and will work just
>   fine in GNOME, KDE, XFCE and others.
>   We do our best to adhere to the 
>   freedesktop standards.

I have the *deluged* daemon run as a service on boot, and also run a client on the same machine that hosts the web interface. I then use the web interface from all my systems.

Comment: I prefer rtorrent, but only because I'm very stingy with my memory and tend to get better performance out of it.

Comment: If your application is fully non-interactive, deluged's interface is nicer. rtorrent is fully ncurses, i.e. interactive.

Comment: As much as I loved deluge when I started, it had some serious problems with the libtorrent library not working with socks5 proxies, and at the time there was no fix, which caused me to move on.

Apparently they've fixed the problem, but I'm not sure if that's made it into the repositories yet, so you may still have to build from source.

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients). I've used rtorrent and i liked it.

Comment: Is rTorrent available for Windows?  (or are there any ports)

Comment: no, i suggested as you tagged it linux, for windows you can use webUI of uTorrent

Answer (score 5):

For Unix-based systems you can use [rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/).

Answer (score 1):

I use the original BitTorrent client, btlaunchmanycurses and btdownloadcurses work fine, specially combined with screen (to allow for unattended downloading).

There is a more detailed description (in French) on [my blog](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/screen-bittorrent.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use `rtorrent` most of the time, running in a `screen`, but for the occasional one-off download I also like to use `aria2`, which I otherwise usually use for managed HTTP downloads.

`aria2` also supports `magnet:` links, which I think I have heard that rtorrent is supposed to do in some version, but doesn't in the old Debian I use. Finally, in `aria2`'s favor (in your case) is that it has less UI than `rtorrent`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have many options.
According to [this page](https://www.slant.co/topics/1284/~best-bittorrent-clients-for-a-linux-server) and my knowledge, you can use any of these:

- qbittorrent-nox
- Deluge
- aria2
- Transmission (daemon)
- rtorrent