# Are there any torrent clients that run as a service?

Tags: windows, bittorrent, services

I turn off all of my computers at night except for my server. I'd like to be able to have my torrent downloads run on my server, which won't be logged in, so I'm wondering if there are any clients that can run as a service.

I'm ideally looking for one that can be passed a path to a .torrent file and will begin downloading it (I'll write the program that will interact with it).

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/35919/which-torrent-apps-work-headless-from-command-line-only

Comment: CLI != Windows Service (though I suppose I could write a service that would invoke the CLI)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uTorrent definitely works as a service (I use it), and there's guides out there (need I say google?)
if you have some preference of client, try searching "install *some_bittorent_client* as a service"

Comment: The problem with doing that is interacting with the service. You can't invoke it with the path to a .torrent and have it being the download. Unless you know of a way?

Comment: you could use uTorrent's webUi to manage it, which can be accessed from other computers than the server itself...not sure if that's the approach you're looking for though

Comment: +1: It's a good idea, but I was looking for something more unattended (if I need to write a service that will invoke the service, that's fine). The workflow I'm looking for is, save the .torrent to a shared folder and everything is taken care of from there.

Comment: uTorrent's webUi can't set download folder, only can save in `C:/user/download/`

Answer (score 7):

Look at [Hadouken](https://github.com/hadouken/hadouken), it is a BitTorrent client for Windows which runs as a Windows Service. It is also free and open source.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author.